# How to get thumbnail URL from RSS feed

Tags: ee5, rss

This script was working in Expression Engine V2 but isn't at version 5.
Can someone tell me how to get the thumnail URL of this rss feed?

Other info is already working..

```
{exp:rss_parser url="https://nieuws.optima.nl/rss" limit="1" refresh="720"}
{media:thumbnail@url} (<-- this is not working)
{/exp:rss_parser}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native RSS parser plugin only has limited functionality so won't work for that. Use https://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/feed_parser instead as it has support for any XML element.